# Функция для получения нажатий кнопок клавиатуры

Tags: c++, winapi

Имеется консольное окно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, WinAPI функцию (или набор функций), которая блокирует вызывающий поток до тех пор, пока не будет нажата какая-либо кнопка на клавиатуре. Необходимо, чтобы эта функция возвращала какую-нибудь информацию о нажатой кнопке.

`_getch()`, как вариант, но это не WinAPI функция.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Взгляните на `ReadConsoleInput`, `PeekConsoleInput` и [иже с ними](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - может, это то, что вы ищете?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

WORD ReadKey(void) {
    const DWORD n = 128;
    INPUT_RECORD rc[n];

    HANDLE hin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    if(hin == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return (WORD)-1;

    DWORD x = 0;
    while(ReadConsoleInput(hin, rc, n, &x)){
        for(DWORD i = 0; i < x; ++i){
            if(rc[i].EventType != KEY_EVENT)
                 continue;

            if(rc[i].Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown)
                 return rc[i].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode;
        }
    }
    return (WORD)-1;
}


int main(void){
    WORD key;
    do {
        key = ReadKey();
        switch(key){
        case VK_RETURN:
            puts("Ентер");
            break;
        case VK_SPACE:
            puts("Пробел");
            break;
        default:
            puts("другая клавиша");
            break;
        }
   } while(key != VK_ESCAPE);
   return 0;
}
```