# Как ожидать ввод с клавиатуры не более k секунд?

Tags: c++, windows, время, потоки-данных

Как в c++ создать ожидание ввода с клавиатуры k секунд?  sleep ведь не может сделать этого? Пример условия: "Выводится строка с двумя случайно сгенерированными числами a и b, программа ожидает 5 секунд ответ (число c) - произведение этих чисел. Если время прошло, вывести "время вышло", иначе вывести 0 или 1 в соответствии с верностью выражения a * b == c".

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Функция для получения нажатий кнопок клавиатуры](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/519169/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d1%8b)

Comment: В PeekConsoleInput указать время.